# Apache CXF Applying SAML Assertion to Payload Header

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using the Apache CXF library to consume a SOAP Web Service. This service requires a `saml:assertion` (SAML 1, not 2) in the payload header. I want to use an encoded SAML token that is given to me. How do I add this token into every request going to the external SOAP Web Service?

I've been playing around with the `AbstractSoapInterceptor` and the `SamlTokenInterceptor`, but I haven't gotten it to work yet. The interceptors require a `Phase` string, and I'm not sure which one suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the CXF system tests. See here for a SAML example:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/9e6d2aa86c57e600baf66e42538036c927cadcf5/systests/ws-security/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/action/ActionTest.java#L423

Spring configuration:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/9e6d2aa86c57e600baf66e42538036c927cadcf5/systests/ws-security/src/test/resources/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/action/client.xml#L351

If you already have a SAML token you can set that on the SAMLCallbackHandler directly via this method:

https://github.com/apache/wss4j/blob/eb3dc39b397f571746ee9183ecb96eac3206fa9f/ws-security-common/src/main/java/org/apache/wss4j/common/saml/SAMLCallback.java#L313